# Check the authenticity of a Les Paul

Tags: electric-guitar

At a local pawn shop I found this guitar sold as an Epiphone Les Paul. The strange thing is that in the head stock there's the Gibson logo not the Epiphone one. The price is affordable and I'd like a Gibson.

Has Gibson ever produced Epiphone Les Pauls with that headstock in the past? The other strange thing is the position of the screw just above the nut. I searched over the internet and all Gibson standard (as well as Les Paul) have that screw centered and well flattened, but in this model is shifted to the left. Second thing in most Gibson standard in the headstock there's written "Les Paul model" here only "Les Paul" as you can see. I'm not very familiar with Gibson I have only a fender so If you have a Gibson such as this let me know what to check to be sure it is an authentic one and if you recognize it which exact model is.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Worth looking for a serial no., and checking against the site.

Comment: See https://www.samash.com/spotlight/a-guide-to-counterfeit-gibson-les-paul-fender-stratocaster-and-ibanez-guitars/

Comment: Yes, don't guitars have serial numbers as well? _Always_ check the serial number if available. Could've been stolen. On guitars they're usually on the back of the headstock or neckplate if I remember correctly.

Comment: Also https://www.guitargear.net.au/discussion/index.php?topic=26412.0 Serial, Gibson & Epiphone, is on the back of the headstock

Answer (score 2):

Frets: not Gibson. On a real Gibson the frets would be filed down at the ends and the binding would cover the tips.

The nut doesn't look like a Gibson either, it looks cheap, square, and the strings sink too much.

The pickups don't look Gibson. Even if you remove the cover, most Gibson LP will have black and white colored hambuckers.

The color of the top, and the finish, don't look like Gibson at all.

Bottom line: if the guitar sounds good and you like it, by all means get it and use it. But a Gibson, it is not.

Comment: I still thnk its an Epiphone that's been tarted up a bit.  MMazzon is right - the nut doesn't look right and the fret ends are finished more cheaply. I think also that from the yellowed look of the plastic parts, its an *older* Epiphone; i had one in tiger stripe sunburst in 1997 and this looks very much like it. The pickups were all black too.  BUT if it plays well, and sounds well, enjoy it.

Comment: It could be a Gibson with a new set of frets.  A lot of people will not salvage the binding.  But I don't think that's the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's an Epiphone and has been garnished with a logo to look like a Gibson. Perhaps the pawn shop know this and are being honest? I've had exactly that model of Epiphone and they are **fine** instruments. Maybe ask them why they think it's an Epiphone?

Comment: Which exact model is it? I thought that headstock style was new for 2021.

Comment: The head stock looks a little odd to me when comparing to other Epiphone images.  It could be a home made Franken-ax.

Comment: headstock looks just like the 90s one i had